# Typescript class variable return undefined inside Firebase function

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular, ionic2

I come from a python/golang background and now I diving into ionic2.
I wonder if I doing something stupid, or there is an issue, which at my current knowledge of the stack, I cannot tell where its from. Maybe I only need a way to reference the outer scope of this function. Well, I am looping through my user collection and get the data printed to the console like this with the code base down below the question:

```
page1.ts:81 key -KFoJ-oF-ll04zmxJZiL
page1.ts:88 data Object {email: "sdcsd@gmail.com", username: "cesscd"}
page1.ts:89 user UserAllowed {email: "sdcsd@gmail.com", username: "cesscd"}
```

But as soon as I try to push a new user to the allowed user array I get  this error;

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'alloweduser' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:98:21
    at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:200:356
    at Kc.h.ka (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:275)
    at Kc.h.ka (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:268)
    at Kc.h.ka (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:268)
    at Kc.h.ka (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:35:268)
    at Ec.h.ka (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:32:465)
    at fe.h.R (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:83:379)
    at W.forEach (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js:200:326)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:88:22
```

### Code base

```
export class Page1 {
    reponse:string;
    firebaseUrl:string;
    userRef:Firebase;
    alloweduser: UserAllowed[];
    constructor() {
        this.firebaseUrl = "https://fghghgf-hefghgfhat-gh.firebaseio.com/web/data/";
        this.userRef = new Firebase(this.firebaseUrl).child("users");
    }

        ngOnInit(){
        this.alloweduser=[];
        this.userRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
            // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                // key will be "fred" the first time and "barney" the second time
                var key = childSnapshot.key();
                console.log("key",key);
                // childData will be the actual contents of the child
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                var user = new UserAllowed("","");
                var user = new UserAllowed(childData.username,childData.email);
                console.log("data",childData);
                console.log("user",user);
                //Why this.alloweduser get undefined inside this function?
                this.alloweduser.push(user);
            });
        });
    }

    }


    // TypeScript
class UserAllowed {
    // Property (public by default)
    email: string;
    username: string;
    // Constructor
    // (accepts a value so you can initialize engine)
    constructor(username:string, email: string) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `this` inside a callback function, where it has a different meaning. One solution is to use fat-arrow/rocket notation for the callback, which ensures `this` is what you expect it to be:

```
    this.userRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
        // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            // key will be "fred" the first time and "barney" the second time
            var key = childSnapshot.key();
            console.log("key",key);
            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var user = new UserAllowed("","");
            var user = new UserAllowed(childData.username,childData.email);
            console.log("data",childData);
            console.log("user",user);
            //Why this.alloweduser get undefined inside this function?
            this.alloweduser.push(user);
        });
    });
```

For more on the meaning of `this`, see [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I works! But still having trouble with 2-way-binding not showing the array

Comment: Might have to make the `function` in the `forEach()` loop an arrow-function as well. Otherwise `this.alloweduser.push()` will fail

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure of that one @PierreDuc, but it could be. I'll update the snippet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Better to not use `function` and always use the arrow notation. The TypeScript compiler will see whether it needs to create an extra scope anyways :)

Comment: i was a cache issue. Works very nice! Firebase rocks